# Discord.js v12 Love Affinity command - cannot mention yourself

Tags: javascript, command, discord.js

so I am having trouble when I use the command `$love @me` it still "calculates" the percentage, I want it to return with a message like "You cannot check your love percentage...", How could I do that?
Also is it possible if you use the command more times, it still outputs the same number between the members, for example: `$love @myfriend`, outputs 74%. then I write the command again, and it types out the same percentage..

Here's my code:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "love")) {
        if(!message.mentions.members.first()) return message.channel.send(`Please mention someone to calculate the love percentage`).then(message.react('❌'));
        let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/)
        let person = message.mentions.members.first(message, args[0]);

        const love = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        const loveIndex = Math.floor(love / 10);
        const loveLevel = "".repeat(loveIndex) + "".repeat(10 - loveIndex);
        
        let loveEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Love percentage")
        .setDescription(`${message.author} loves ${person} this much: ${love}%\n\n${loveLevel}`)
        message.channel.send(loveEmbed)
    }
})
```

Hopefully someone can help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an if statement and check the IDs

```js
if(person.id === msg.author.id) return msg.channel.send("Can't mention yourself");
```

So:

```js
let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/)
let person = message.mentions.members.first(message, args[0]);
if(person.id === msg.author.id) return msg.channel.send("Can't mention yourself");
```

Also somewhat unrelated but the paramaters here are useless:

```js
message.mentions.members.first(message, args[0]);
```

The only argument is the amount, so passing in message and args[0] has no affect. Unless you used a library which tempered with the collection class

Comment: Thanks, worked, I've tried a similar code like that but seems like I had an error somewhere.